# Insert or change a column position in dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe, I usually use the `cbind` command for adding columns to the end of a dataframe. This time I want to insert a column and make it the first column in the dataframe.
I have found similar questions online but the suggested methods were really complicated, like establishing the dataframe from the beginning, is there a simple way to achieve this in one go?

I have a a matrix of 457 column and 9628 row.

Thanks,

Comment: can this be done without `cbind` I wonder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the column to be the first, just switch the order in `cbind`:

```
cbind(c=1:2,data.frame(a=c("a","b"),b=3:4))
```

Or just order the columns afterwards.

Comment: Hi @Roland, I want to try the command on my data. Can you please explain to me what the a,b and c represent? Many thanks

Comment: @Error404 I guess they are just dummy values used to show an example

Comment: @Michele, I understand they are dummy values. I am asking what should I replace "a" with? is it the column I want to add? or it is it the dataframe? or maybe it is part of the command? I don't know the structure of the formula. Same goes for B and C.

Comment: If you don't understand this you should read an introduction to R. This is extremely basic stuff.

Comment: I almost finished writing 3 programs in R, Just not familiar with this particular case. I will try to read the cbind help file. Thank you.

Comment: @Error404 that's impressive.. in particular because you've done that without knowing the concept of `named vector` and/or `named list`..

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you should just switch the ordering of the variables in the arguments to cbind()..

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),ncol=3)
B <- c(4,5)
C <- cbind(B,A)
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything beyond @Roland's answer.